# Extension taking too long to initialize

Tags: ios, objective-c, sdk, ios8-today-widget, today-extension

I have a Today widget extension, in which the `viewDidLoad:` method, I am calling a method, `unloadClipboard:`, the method contains a bit that gets called, which converts the user's image clipboard into NSData. Everything in theory should work fine, however, the widget crashes on this code, because it takes too long to initialize–even though I am running it on a background thread.

```
if (copiedImage && self.imageFunctionalityEnabled) {
        //Item is an image, get data

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT), ^{

            NSData *data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard] image], 0.032);

            //If data isn't already added
            if (![imageArray containsObject:data]) {
                [imageArray addObject:data];
            }

            //Sync the defaults
            [defaults setObject:imageArray forKey:@"imagesArray"];
            [defaults synchronize];

            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[imageArray lastObject]];

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                _imageView.image = image;

            });

        });

    } else if (copiedString && ![textArray containsObject:copiedString]) {

        [textArray addObject:copiedString];
        [defaults setObject:textArray forKey:@"array"];
        [defaults setObject:imageArray forKey:@"imagesArray"];
        _imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[imageArray lastObject]];

    } else {
        [defaults setObject:imageArray forKey:@"imagesArray"];
        _imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[imageArray lastObject]];
    }
```

After some breakpoints, NSLogs, and time profiling the widget target, I came to the conclusion that this line, is the line supposedly taking too long.

```
NSData *data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard] image], 0.032);
```

Here is an example of a crash report:

> Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT) Exception Subtype: LAUNCH_HANG
>   Exception Message: The extension took too much time to initialize

I have successfully isolated the issue also by commenting out code from that block, in which the widget ran fine. Any help is appreciated.

**Update: here is the code with the changes:**

```
if (copiedImage && self.imageFunctionalityEnabled) {
        //Item is an image, get data

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

            NSData *data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(copiedImage, 0.032);

            //If data isn't already added
            if (![imageArray containsObject:data]) {
                [imageArray addObject:data];
            }

            //Sync the defaults
            [defaults setObject:imageArray forKey:@"imagesArray"];
            [defaults synchronize];

            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[imageArray lastObject]];

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                _imageView.image = image;

            });

        });

    } else if (copiedString && ![textArray containsObject:copiedString]) {

        [textArray addObject:copiedString];
        [defaults setObject:textArray forKey:@"array"];
        [defaults setObject:imageArray forKey:@"imagesArray"];
        _imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[imageArray lastObject]];

    } else {
        [defaults setObject:imageArray forKey:@"imagesArray"];
        _imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[imageArray lastObject]];
    }
```

**Here are the logs:**

> Dec  1 18:41:57 Isa-Ranjhas-iPhone ReportCrash[7074] :
>   Formulating crash report for process CopyfeedWidget[7073] Dec  1
>   18:41:57 Isa-Ranjhas-iPhone CopyfeedWidget[7073] : VIEW WILL
>   APPEAR Dec  1 18:41:57 Isa-Ranjhas-iPhone SpringBoard[328] :
>   plugin com.isaranjha.Copyfeed.CopyfeedWidget interrupted Dec  1
>   18:41:57 Isa-Ranjhas-iPhone SpringBoard[328] : plugin
>   com.isaranjha.Copyfeed.CopyfeedWidget invalidated Dec  1 18:41:57
>   Isa-Ranjhas-iPhone mediaserverd[22] : '' (pid = 7073) setting
>   DiscoveryMode = DiscoveryMode_None, currentDiscoveryMode =
>   DiscoveryMode_PresenceScan Dec  1 18:41:57 Isa-Ranjhas-iPhone
>   assertiond[63] : pid_suspend failed for : Unknown error: -1, Unknown error: -1 Dec  1 18:41:57
>   Isa-Ranjhas-iPhone assertiond[63] : assertion failed: 12B436:
>   assertiond + 57724 [10EC04AD-D18F-3ECD-8A8E-FBB1CC4E2BD6]: 0x3 Dec  1
>   18:41:57 Isa-Ranjhas-iPhone assertiond[63] : Could not set
>   priority of  to 2,
>   priority: No such process Dec  1 18:41:57 Isa-Ranjhas-iPhone
>   assertiond[63] : Could not set priority of  to 4096, priority: No such process Dec  1 18:41:57
>   Isa-Ranjhas-iPhone SpringBoard[328] : Widget with identifier
>   'com.isaranjha.Copyfeed.CopyfeedWidget' disconnected unexpectedly Dec 
>   1 18:41:57 Isa-Ranjhas-iPhone pkd[5114] : assigning plug-in
>   com.isaranjha.Copyfeed.CopyfeedWidget(1.0) to plugin sandbox Dec  1
>   18:41:57 Isa-Ranjhas-iPhone pkd[5114] : enabling pid=328 for
>   plug-in com.isaranjha.Copyfeed.CopyfeedWidget(1.0)
>   CAF48DC4-9AD3-4E4F-82F5-F77903676E1F
>   /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/E12BF21F-02A5-4E06-8D4C-CA2DEBCA3850/Copyfeed.app/PlugIns/CopyfeedWidget.appex

Comment: Why you are updating in secondary thread ??

Comment: Should the UI not be updated on main thread? And the heavy lifting of compression of an image, be done on another thread to take away from prolonging the launch time?

Comment: Try updating your UI stuff in this             dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

Comment: Am I not already doing so?

Comment: I don't know if this is causing the problem, but you have your arguments to `dispatch_get_global_queue` backwards. You need to make `DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT` the first argument, not the second.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be the cause of the problem. Thank you for the correction though.